# Github API v3 query top 10

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to tell the github api to return me the top 10 users by part of username for the sake of autocomplete feature. I am trying to use the search api:

> http://developer.github.com/v3/search/

I tried ?top=10 and ?limit=10 and ?page=0&per_page=10, but they seem to fail to work. Is there any way to do this or i'll just have to filter 10 of 100 always?

Comment: I'm not sure you can search for users by specifying only a prefix of the username. Are you sure you can do that? What is the exact request you are making? Other than that -- pagination rules are defined by http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it so I reached out to GitHub for help. It seems there is no way to limit it in the request for legacy APIs and the advice is to limit the list at the client.